# Propriedade não é reconhecida ao utilizar @Input em uma diretiva

Tags: angular

Considere a seguinte diretiva:

```
import {Directive, HostListener, HostBinding, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[myHighlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {

    @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseOver() {
        this.backgroundColor = this.hightLightColor;
    }

    @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
        this.backgroundColor = this.defaultColor;
    }

    @HostBinding('style.backgroundColor') backgroundColor:string;

    @Input() defaultColor:string = 'white';
    @Input() hightLightColor:string = 'yellow';

    constructor() {
    }

}
```

Repare que foram criadas 2 variáveis `defaultColor` e `hightLightColor` utilizando o decorator `@Input`.

No HTML do componente, adicionei o *input property*:

```
<p myHighlight [defaultcolor]="'grey'" [hightlightcolor]="'red'">
    Texto highlight
</p>
```

Porém no browser ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: 
Can't bind to 'defaultcolor' since it isn't a known property of 'p'.

<p myHighlight [ERROR ->][defaultcolor]="'grey' [hightlightcolor]="'red'">
    Texto highlight
</p>

Can't bind to 'hightlightcolor' since it isn't a known property of 'p'.

<p myHighlight [defaultcolor]="'grey'" [ERROR ->] [hightlightcolor]="'red'">
    Texto highlight
</p>
```

O que está errado no código para que as propriedades `defaultcolor` e `hightlightcolor` não sejam reconhecidas?

Comment: Mudei o nome das variáveis e funcionou. Voltei a por o nome antigo e funcionou na mesma. Há alguma cache quando se utiliza o `ng server` no CLI?

Comment: Coloque sua solução como resposta,  Filipe. Pode ajudar alguém com o mesmo problema.

Comment: @PabloAlmeida não chega a ser uma solução. Na verdade não entendi ainda o que se passou, utilizei os comentários para adicionar a informação por não ser uma resposta concreta.